# Error when trying to query from multiple sheets in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a relatively big Google Sheet. All of its sheets are build the same, just the values are different.

The following query works fine:

`=QUERY('12th November - 18th November'!E:H,"select E, sum(H), sum(G) where E is not null group by E order by sum(H) desc limit 5 label sum(G) 'Q Sessions', sum(H) 'Revenue'",1)`

But when I try to add another sheet to the query like this:
`=QUERY({'12th November - 18th November'!E:H;'29th October - 4th November'!E:H},"select E, sum(H), sum(G) where E is not null group by E order by sum(H) desc limit 5 label sum(G) 'Q Sessions', sum(H) 'Revenue'",1)`

I get the following error:
**Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: E**

I tried the query with one sheet for all my sheets and it always works.
Just when I try to add another sheet to the query I get the error.
So the column E is definitely there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you construct an array, you lose the references so you must use the Col# notation.

`=QUERY({'12th November - 18th November'!E:H;'29th October - 4th November'!E:H},"select Col1, sum(Col4), sum(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 order by sum(Col4) desc limit 5 label sum(Col3) 'Q Sessions', sum(Col4) 'Revenue'",1)`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works like a charm. 
I was not aware that you have to use the Col# notation in such cases.